# byte[] to image convertion in windows phone 7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I am doing an application for windows phone 7.
the application is access a image from database(Sql server 2008).
the data is stored in data type 'image'.I want to Display the image.
i use the following code

```
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,           System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        byte[] data;
        BitmapImage empImage = new BitmapImage(); 
        Stream mm;
        data = (byte[])value;
        mm = new MemoryStream(data);
        mm.Position = 0;
        BinaryReader BR = new BinaryReader(mm);
        byte[] image=BR.ReadBytes(data.Length);
        mm = new MemoryStream(image);
        //empImage.SetSource(mm);
        return empImage;
    }
```

But there is a 'Unspecified' error at commented line (empImage.SetSource(mm);).

Please help Me......

Answer (score 0):

`BitmapImage.SetSource` accepts a `Stream` (you can leave out the CreateOptions if you don't need to access the bytes immediately afterwards):

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    byte[] data = (byte[])value;

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage
        {
            CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None
        };

        image.SetSource(stream);

        return image;
    }
}
```

Also, I don't think an `IValueConverter` is the right place for this sort of code.

And finally, the `image` database type has been deprecated in favour of `varbinary(MAX)`

Comment: Never mind, it was voted down because a `BitmapSource` can't be instantiated.